# How to overload operator<< to output a vector, defined inside a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

The example below is a distilled version of a problem with templates I'm having - please see compilation errors below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T> struct S
{
  typedef std::vector<T> SVec;
};

template <class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& OS, const S<T>::SVec& X)
{
  for (const auto& e: X) OS << e << ' ';
  return OS;
}

int main()
{
  S<int>::SVec v;
  std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
g++ -g -Wall -O4 -std=c++11 -c tc041.cpp
tc041.cpp:22:69: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘S<T>::SVec’ because ‘S<T>’ is a dependent scope
 template <class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& OS, const S<T>::SVec& X)
```

And so on - hundreds of lines.
My compiler - g++ 5.2.1, OS - Xubuntu 4.2.0.

How to make this operator to be compiled correctly?

Comment: The error message is actually very literal, although it requires some more knowledge to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

- Missing `typename` keyword at the operator declaration.
- Template type deduction fails in `main`.

---

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& OS, const typename S<T>::SVec& X)
```

A `typename` keyword should be placed before `S<T>::SVec`. Due to language rules, the compiler does not know whether `SVec` is a member type or something else. The `typename` keyword is to tell the compiler it is a type.

For details of the language rules, you may refer to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

---

(Note: I am actually less sure about it because this scenario is new to me too.)

Let's do an experiment. Instead of invoking `operator<<` with operator syntax, let's invoke it with function syntax.

```
operator<< (std::cout, v);
```

Well, it still fails.

What if we invoke it with explicit template argument?

```
operator<< <int> (std::cout, v);
```

It works! Well, actually, may work. I find that some standard library header may contain something that interferes it. But let's put it aside.

The problem this experiment demonstrates is that the template argument deduction fails. Argument type of the form `class-template-name<T>::member-type` cannot be deduced.

Details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: Thank you, it helps. Any way to "help" the compiler to deduce the argument?

Comment: @HEKTO I don't have a good solution. You may consider taking `std::vector<T>` or `S<T>`.